# For $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$, when is $A+A^T$ positive semi-definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

> Let $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$. What are conditions on $A$ that ensure that $A+A^T$ is p.s.d. ?

Since $x^TA^Tx= ( x^TA^Tx)^T   =x^TAx$, $A+A^T$ is positive semi-definite if and only if $\forall x\in \mathbb R^n, x^TAx\geq 0$.

Is there a caracterization of non-symmetric matrices that verify $\forall x\in \mathbb R^n, x^TAx\geq 0$ (in terms of eigenvalues e.g.) ?

Comment: $x^t Ax\neq tr(x^tAx)$!

Comment: @pigeon $x^TAx \in \mathbb R$, so $x^TAx = tr(x^TAx)$.

Comment: Of course, there was no reason to use the trace. For any $1\times 1$ matrix (i.e., scalar) $a, a^T = a$, which justifies the calculation directly.

Comment: First, we use Schur Decomposition to obtain the eigenvalues. After then, it is an easy procedure to check whether they are all non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example which shows that there is no characterization "in terms of eigenvalues".

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ and let $B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 3\\
0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$. Then both $A$ and $B$ have eigenvalues $1, 2$.

But $A + A^T$ is positive definite, while $B + B^T$ is not positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 1):

This seems equivalent to the condition of $A$ being an "accretive operator" (from this [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10114-019-8478-2))

[image]

Looking at the action of $B$ from the example above, you can see that for quite a few vectors it takes them into opposite direction, so it's not accretive.

[image]

From algebraic viewpoint, this comes down to asking whether numerical range of $A$ contains the origin. Called "zero inclusion question" in this [paper](https://users.math.msu.edu/users/shapiro/pubvit/Downloads/NumZero/numzero.pdf).

The reason for this is the connection between numeric range of $A$ and symmetric part of $A$, see Mark Embers [slides](https://www.google.com/search?q=mark+embers+pseudospectra+dynamical+systems&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS884US884&sxsrf=ALiCzsaA_oKKXlIrdP3smcPCX9tIGabnpQ%3A1660591790900&ei=rp76YpnLNs7VkPIPgYmiwAw&ved=0ahUKEwiZ2sC-ysn5AhXOKkQIHYGECMgQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=mark+embers+pseudospectra+dynamical+systems&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABMgUIIRCrAjoHCAAQRxCwA0oECEEYAEoECEYYAFDaDVirV2D7V2gBcAF4AIABiAGIAc8MkgEEMTIuNZgBAKABAcgBA8ABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz).

[image]

Matrices $A$ and $B$ in WhatsUp example above have same eigenvalues, but different numeric ranges

[image]

[image]

We can visualize numeric range for 3 representative examples

1. $X+X^T$ positive definite

[image]

2. $X+X^T$ positive semidefinite but not positive definite
   [image]
3. $X+X^T$ not positive semidefinite

[image]

[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/math-psd-learning-rate.nb)