# When is $A+A^T$ positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $A$ is a real valued $d\times d$ matrix.

1. Is there a way to characterize set of $A$ such that that it's "symmetrization" $B$ is positive definite?

$$B=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$$

Largest eigenvalue of $B$ is known as the numerical abscissa of $A$ and [determines](http://www2.mpi-magdeburg.mpg.de/mpcsc/events/trogir/slides/psa_slides.pdf) the starting slope of $\text{exp}(t A)$

2. Is there meaning attached to the "smallest eigenvalue" of $B$?

(prompted by related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4512245/998) where this condition on $A=CD$ with p.s.d $C,D$ turns out necessary for random update $x=x-\alpha C x$ on $x$ with covariance matrix $D$ to reduce variance of $x$ in all directions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that a square matrix $A$ is positive definite if and only if $A$+ $A^T$ is positive definite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693828/prove-that-a-square-matrix-a-is-positive-definite-if-and-only-if-a-at-is)

Comment: Positive define requires symmetry, this seems too strict since this may hold for non symmetric A

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3529411/for-a-in-mathbb-rn-times-n-when-is-aat-p-s-d

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov but in $x^TAx$, only the symmetric part contributes.

Comment: $B$ is the symmetric part, so the question is "Which $A$'s have positive definite symmetric part"?

Comment: @GabrielRomon indeed, it's similar, but it restricts attention to eigenvalues of $A$ which is answered in the negative. I'm curious if it can be characterized in terms of other quantities, like numeric range of $A$

Comment: The answer is trivial. Any sum of antisymmetric matrix and a positive definite matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found relevant information in Horn/Johnson, "Topics in Matrix Analysis" and "On the Origin and Numerical Range of Bounded Operators."

Restricting to real values, the following seem to be true:

- $A+A^T$ is positive definite if $\langle x, Ax \rangle>0$ for all $x!=0$
- Re($\langle x, Ax \rangle$) for $\|x\|=1$ takes values in $[\lambda_\text{min}(A+A^T),\lambda_\text{max}(A+A^T)]$, page 37 of Mark Embrees "Pseudospectra and the Behavior of Dynamical Systems" [slides](https://cscproxy.mpi-magdeburg.mpg.de/mpcsc/events/trogir/slides/psa_slides.pdf)
- $A+A^T$ positive definite implies $A$ is positive stable
- Gersgorin regions G(A) in right halfplane implies $A+A^T$ is positive definite

---

Relevant excerpt from Horn/Johnson

[image]

Relevant excerpt from "On the Origin and Numerical Range of Bounded Operators"

[image]